# Getting the following error... Searched but not able to solve the problem. please help

Tags: mount

Error mounting system-managed device /dev/sdb: Command-line `mount "/mnt/usb-Sony_Storage_Media_CB0000FFFFFFFD20800B7-0:0"' exited with non-zero exit status 32: mount: /dev/sdb: can't read superblock
 (udisks-error-quark, 0)

Comment: You're trying to mount a raw drive, are you sure there is no partitions on it? (-> mount /dev/sdb1). Are you sure this drive is formated?

Comment: yes i'm sure there is no partition in it. I have tried formatting the pendrive in both ubuntu as well as windows.

Comment: In ubuntu the error is " mount: /dev/sdb: can't read superblock" and in windows it says "unable to format completely"

Comment: If you can't format it, it is perhaps broken